# Homeomorphism between subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

How to establish a homeomorphism between the "closed unit ball minus origin" and the "complement of open unit ball"? In other words, how to establish a homeomorphism between $X$ and $Y$, where $X=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n;\;0<|x|\leq 1\}$ and $Y=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n;\;|y|\geq 1\}$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‘Reflect’ in the unit sphere:

$$x\leftrightarrow\frac1{\|x\|^2}x$$

Comment: Can you give me more details?

Comment: @Perguntador: All you have to show is that the map that I gave you is an open, continuous bijection from $X$ to $Y$ (or from $Y$ to $X$: it works both ways).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott   The denominator in your formula should be the square of the length of $x$, so that you're reflecting in the unit sphere, not projecting to the unit sphere.

Comment: @Andreas: Yikes! Thanks very much.

Comment: @Perguntador: Please note that I had a mental hiccup and left an exponent out of my original answer; it’s fixed now. As compensation for the misleading original version, let me add that what this does to $x$ is replace it with a point $y$ in the same direction from the origin and such that $\|y\|=\frac1{\|x\|}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Can I to show that the map is closed instead of open? What's easiest?

Comment: @Perguntador: Actually, the easiest of all is to show that both it and its inverse are continuous, because it **is** its inverse.